# Em um programa de console em C#, onde é definido a classe principal?

Tags: c#, .net, classes, monodevelop

Estou fazendo meu primeiro programa de console em C#, apenas para fazer alguns testes.

Tenho duas classes: `HelloConsole.MainClass` e `HelloConsole.Calc`.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
using System;

// Aprendendo o alias de namespace

using C = System.Console;

namespace HelloConsole
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Calc calc = new Calc (3);

            /** 
             * Agora já sei que WriteLine aceita múltiplos parâmetros
             * Tipo o Python
             * */

            C.WriteLine ("O valor é {0}", calc.value);

            C.WriteLine ("Soma de {0}", calc.sum (3));

            C.WriteLine ("Multiplo de 3 é {0}", calc.mul(3));

            Calc calc_2 = new Calc (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

            C.WriteLine("Valores da instância diferente {0}", calc_2.value);

            C.WriteLine ("Valores de multiplicação é {0}", calc_2.mul(5));



        }
    }
}
```

Esse programa funciona perfeitamente. E eu entendi que tudo que é colocando dentro do método estático `Main` é executado no console. Porém ainda não entendi onde é que o compilador "sabe" que é a `MainClass` que é a classe principal.

Isso é definido em algum lugar, ou o Compilador do C# entende que é a classe principal por causa do nome `MainClass`?

É possível definir outra classe principal?

É possível ter mais de uma classe principal?

**Nota**: Estou usando Linux e compilando pelo Monodevelop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quando tem apenas uma classe com `Main()` em todo o projeto (onde vai gerar um *assembly* (arquivo executável) o compilador se vira em achar qual é ela já que não há ambiguidade. O nome da classe pouco importa.

Quando tem mais que uma classe com o método chamado de *entry point* (o que parece estar sendo chamado de "classe principal" na pergunta), aí tem que definir na compilação qual deve ser usado com a *flag* de compilação `/main`:

```
/main:NomeDaClass
```

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/main-compiler-option?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

No Visual Studio em `Startup Object`:

[image: SS Visual Studo Startup Object]

Não tenho o MonoDevelop, mas tem algum lugar pra configurar isto. Só achei como fazer meio manual:

[image: SS MonoDevelop]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).